# SSRS subscription- predefined delivery

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I just want to ask if SSRS is capable of doing a predefined delivery for subscription.

If for example, I can expect a report to be emailed to me with the data from today and last 7 days ?

Below is what the fields look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either:

1. Using expressions, or a dataset using the necessary logic, configure the default values of a report to populate with the values you'd need
2. Use Data Driven subscriptions, along with a query that will return the values you'd need.  See here for some information:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx

At the moment, it looks like your report simply doesn't provide any defaults, so you could use something like:

**Date From**

```
=DateAdd("d", -7, Today())
```

**Date To**

```
=Today()
```